# Tomcat doesn't start .war file from Grails

Tags: tomcat, grails, deployment, war

I am using Grails 1.3.7 and Tomcat 8.

I created a .war file from my Grails Application to start it in tomcat 8. I created it using the `grails war` command.

I stopped tomcat. Then i put the .war file in the webapps folder and started tomcat again.
When i go to the Web Application Manager there is my app but not started. If i click on `Start` nothing is happening. Also if i upload it in the deploy form I can find it in the Manager but not started.

I dont get error messages. What can I do to get it started?

Here is my stacktrace.log file.

```
2014-02-17 11:12:05,757 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Sanitizing stacktrace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
[...]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    ... 3 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:343)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2334)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2371)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:378)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.getMetaData(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:254)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:292)
    ... 14 more
```

DataSource.groovy:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = false
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/OptMan?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
    username = "root"
    password = "123456"
    dbCreate = "create-drop"
    //dbCreate = "update"
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = true
    cache.provider_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
}

environments {
    production {
        dataSource {
            pooled = false
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/OptMan?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
            username = "root"
            password = "123456"
            dbCreate = "create-drop"
            //dbCreate = "update"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post Tomcat logs otherwise it's impossible to help you

Comment: @lukelazarovic edited description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you haven't properly configured `dataSource` for `production` environment. See this: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSourcesAndEnvironments

Comment: Anyway, it seems that you haven't specified enough credentials to connect to your production db. Do you really connect as `root` user? And do you need to `create-drop` your production DB?

Comment: I configured the datasource for production wrong. I edited it and now it works. Thats a lot